# Table or view does not exist - Oracle complains about a comma rather than an actual table or view name

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, ora-00942

I've never seen this before... I have a query that starts off like this:

```
with q1 as
     (select a.V_ID, a.D_ID, a.C_ID,
               case when a.percent > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' end L_val,
               a.C_val
       from ab_a_table a
       where a.C_ID =  '00000003' -- '00000007' --  test values
             and a.B_VAL = '6010001'
             and a.Q = '11234567')
select case
           when ... /* rest of query omitted */
```

When I try to run this, Oracle complains about that a `table or view does not exist`. But *it highlights the ','* on line 3, rather than an actual table/view name:

```
               case when a.percent > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' end L_VAL,
                                                                  *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

The rest of the query I omitted is rather long and complex - I'll sanitize and post it if necessary - for now I'll just say that this error only started when I added a third subquery that referenced `q1`. In fact, it seems I can remove any one of the 3 subqueries and the whole thing will execute (though with incorrect results) so it feels like I've hit some kind of Oracle error rather than a pure SQL error. It's also interesting that I can run the body of `q1` as a stand-alone query and it has no problems when I do that. Only when I run the entire query does it complain about the comma after the case in `q1`.

Has anyone ever experienced this?

(using Oracle 10g).

---

Edit: Tried added `AS` keyword. Results are now:

```
               case when a.perc_fault > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' end AS L_VAL, a.C_VAL
                                                                     *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

It looks like the asterisk is in the same position, but under the `V` because the word `L_VAL` has been shifted by 3 characters. Very strange...

Comment: This is kind of a long-shot, but try changing the line in question to "case when a.percent > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' end AS L_VAL" - in other words, add the "AS" keyword.

Comment: @Bob Jarvis: I added the `AS` keywored, results now in the question.

Comment: Apparently the error is outside of the common table expression, so you should post your complete statement. I strongly assume that the highlighting is simply pointing to the wrong location - whatever tool that is that does the highlighting, because "Oracle" doesn't do error highlighting

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: what patch level are you at? There was a bug fix in the 10.2.0.4 patchset related to ORA-00942 and WITH clauses: 5130732. It's a bit vague but looks like the optimizer is messing up, so I could believe adding or removing a subquery could make a difference. (Also the example in the bug report points to line 3 too).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: It's SQLPlus (an Oracle tool) which is highlighting the wrong part of the query. I'll try to clean up the rest enough so that I can post it, it will take some time...

Comment: @Alex Poole: I think we're on 10.2.0.3.0 here. It's not my call to upgrade :(

Comment: @Alex Poole: I don't know - is there a way that I could change the optimizer's behaviour; can't query hints do that?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: the Metalink note and bug don't suggest any workaround. You could try hints, but no idea what might help - case of suck it and see I fear. (PUSH_SUBQ, UNNEST or NO_UNNEST perhaps...). Otherwise you'll have to redesign the query to avoid the joins. Only other thing that occurs is making a function returning a refcursor, and replacing the subquery with cursors inside that. Potential performance implications whatever you do though.

Comment: If the problem is the WITH clause bug Alan Poole describes try changing the WITH clause to an inline view. Or create an actual view.

Comment: @redcayuga: Thanks, that was our local DBA's opinion too. I'll try it later today and see how it goes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are hitting the Oracle bug(s) and can't patch the database, you could try moving the subquery to a function. Not entirely sure this will work, and assumes your PL/SQL version is in a package, or there's one available that can have a function added:

In the package spec:

```
type q1_rec is record(
    d_id ab_a_table.v_id%TYPE,
    v_id ab_a_table.d_id%TYPE,
    c_id ab_a_table.c_id%TYPE,
    l_val char(1),
    c_val ab_a_table.c_val%TYPE);
type q1_arr is varray(9999); -- assuming you can pick a max size
function q1 return q1_arr pipelined;
pragma restrict_references(q1, wnds);
```

In the package body:

```
function q1 return q1_arr pipelined is
    cursor c is
        select a.V_ID, a.D_ID, a.C_ID,
               case when a.percent > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' end L_val,
               a.C_val
       from ab_a_table a
       where a.C_ID =  '00000003' -- '00000007' --  test values
             and a.B_VAL = '6010001'
             and a.Q = '11234567');
begin
    for r in c loop
        pipe row(r);
    end loop;
end;
```

And then in your main query replace the subquery with `table(q1())`.

Using a ref cursor or nested table might be a bit neater but would need a table type built outside the package, which I guess you want to avoid based on your extra-object comment about using a view.

Comment: I will probably be going in this direction, but need some time to figure out how to break things apart...

Comment: My code sn't exactly the same but the idea is similar - I broke the giant query's subqueries apart into 3 cursors, and then wrapped the whole thing inside a function with about a dozen lines to control which query to run. It's ugly but it works and since the function exists inside my script I don't even have to compile any packages! :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure if I'm experience Oracle bug 5130732 but it sure feels like it. Anyway, I rewrote the query like this:

```
select case ... 
from
    (select ...
     from (select a.V_ID, a.D_ID, a.C_ID,
               case when a.percent > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' end L_val,
               a.C_val
       from ab_a_table a
       where a.C_ID =  '00000003' -- '00000007' --  test values
             and a.B_VAL = '6010001'
             and a.Q = '11234567') q1,  <other tables>
    where ...) subquery1,
    (select ...
     from (select a.V_ID, a.D_ID, a.C_ID,
               case when a.percent > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' end L_val,
               a.C_val
       from ab_a_table a
       where a.C_ID =  '00000003' -- '00000007' --  test values
             and a.B_VAL = '6010001'
             and a.Q = '11234567') q1,  <other tables>
    where ...) subquery2,
    (select ...
     from (select a.V_ID, a.D_ID, a.C_ID,
               case when a.percent > 0 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' end L_val,
               a.C_val
       from ab_a_table a
       where a.C_ID =  '00000003' -- '00000007' --  test values
             and a.B_VAL = '6010001'
             and a.Q = '11234567') q1,  <other tables>
    where ...) subquery3, <other tables>
where....
```

Yes, I included a copy of `q1` in every subquery that used it and everything works fine now. A real view would have worked too, but this was easier (politically, that is - no code-promotion requests to the environment where the analysis needs to be done, no meetings about late-added object in database, etc...)

---

**UPDATE**

And now that I've added the query to my PL/SQL script, Oracle gives me `ORA-00600 [qcscpqbTxt], [600]`, which seems to be related to Oracle bug #5765958.... * sigh *... Can anyone suggest a workaround? I don't have metalink access (well, I might, through a DBA, if this can somehow get onto their radar).

Comment: Your DBA may already know as the ORA-600 will be in the alert log. 5765968 seems to refer to ANSI joins and/or bind variables; guess your PL/SQL version will have variables instead of the hard-coded values. There are also references to 5532110 but can't see any details on that. Can't see a workaround mentioned either. It isn't clear if it's still the subqueries causing the problem, but seems likely I suppose. I'd possibly still consider a local function returning a ref cursor in your PL/SQL, if only in the hope that the optimiser wouldn't try to be too clever. Have you tried hints here too?

Comment: @Alex Poole: Earlier today the DBA sent me the trace file of the error. He said he might start contacting Oracle but I'm going to try the code-mixed-with-query to separate things out first.